# How are RF Waves transmitted?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radio, radio-frequency

What is the mode of transmission for RF waves at 1800 MHz. Is it ground wave propagation, Line of Sight Propagation or Atmospheric reflection (from ionosphere).
What are the different ways for different frequencies of RF waves?

Comment: is this a homework problem?

Comment: No. This is not homework problem. I asked it to understand other topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are some general rules.

Low-frequency EM waves (up to about 500kHz) propagate mostly by ground wave.

Medium-to-high-frequency EM waves (500kHz to 30mHz) propagate by ground wave and by ionospheric reflection.

High frequency waves (above roughly 50mHz) propagate by line-of-sight.

Answer (score 0):

Frequency is essential in this discussion. What happens at 50 MHz is irrelevant at 1800 MHz. At 1800 MHz waves travel by line of site. They can be impacted by tropospheric ducting and I believe also by thunderstorms.

Search for radio propagation in Wikipedia - insufficient prior research.

Comment: tropospheric scatter (not ducting) in tactical comm can be used, and is used up to 6GHz, see AN/PRC-97